# htaccess mod_rewrite cakephp folder inside rule

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite

One small question for the one that know the syntax of `mod_rewrite.`

I have a `cakephp app` on a domain. And the `.htaccess` file there is pretty straightforward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

But I would like to add a directory, let's call it **"test_dir"** so that when in the browser I type `domain.com/test_dir/` it will go to that `test_dir` directory and not `app/webroot/`

I tried this and succeeded only in a way, by typing only

```
RewriteRule    ^test_dir.$ test_dir/ [L]
```

But like this, as it is normal, the other rule isn't no more.
So is there an `"if"` statement or something like that?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

   RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test_dir/.*
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, after asking the question I searched some more and found the rewritecond but didn't know how to use it correctly. Thanks